# Use of unless operator

Tags: ruby

I'm learning the "Ruby Way" and having fun, but, I have this block that works as intended, though I know it could be better. Can someone show me the proper way to use `unless`? This is in a UsersController.

```
def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy unless current_user.admin? 
  flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
  redirect_to users_path      
end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "better"? What is "improper" about this usage?

Comment: that's what I don't know. Is this acceptable?

Comment: This is only acceptable if you want to show a message "User destroyed" even if that isn't the case. What behavior do you want if it IS an admin user performing the destroy? (that logic seems backwards by the way)

Comment: i'm learning - what I've found with ruby is if it sounds retarded when you say it out loud, it probably is.

Answer (score 3):

You will set the flash message no matter whether the user is destroyed.

In your case, you should use if.

```
def destroy
  if current_user.admin?
      User.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
  else
      flash[:success] = "You can't destroy user."    
  end
  redirect_to users_path
end
```

Comment: This looks good, but it is changing the logic from the question. I'm assuming this is what the OP wants though.

Comment: When you ask for something "better", then prepare to have your logic changed.

Comment: @AlexWayne But I'm sure the op's logic is wrong, it must be `if` current_user is admin, then he could destroy user.

Comment: you are partially correct. I'll answer my own question below. I wanted to use "unless" because I wanted to try to make the code more compact.

Comment: What you didn't know is that there is a conditional link item for delete that is hidden from all except admin. Otherwise, this one is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

The way you wrote the code is actually the most concise; although you probably want to make the entire thing a block. That way when you call destroy, "User destroyed." won't be printed and redirect_to users_path won't be called, when the account wasn't actually deleted.

```
def destroy
  unless current_user.admin?
      User.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
      redirect_to users_path
  end

end
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I tried that (almost). Forgot to put the extra "end" so it didn't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GregWallace Are you sure you want this? Normal user can destroy user while admin can not?

Comment: a normal user cannot destroy a user because the actual link with the command to destroy is not rendered unless the user is admin. There are other mechanisms that allow only admin to delete. You may be correct, but it would have to be really sneaky :-) I'll research your idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is as compact as I could think to make it after all the helpful suggestions

```
def destroy
      User.find(params[:id]).destroy 
      flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
      redirect_to users_path

      unless current_user.admin? 

  end
end
```